# Retrieve and display inline images from email when encoded as a CID with c#

Tags: c#, email, imageurl, eml

I need the image URL from the following cid code in the physical path

```
<img id="Picture_x0020_6" src="cid:image001.png@0e4yt5586.A7D64B40" alt="cid:image009.png@34ty6CC2.1CD154B0" />
```

as

```
<img id="Picture_x0020_6" src="~/images/image009.png" alt="image009.png" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the corresponding hidden attachment and then save it on the disk. The [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method of the `Attachment` class saves the attachment to the specified path. Then you can upload it to any web server or just make it available globally and change the `src` attribute in the message body.